# Hiearchical Routing in Single Page Application

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am building a single page app. I have been playing with AngularJS. I'm a little nervous about 2.0 so I am open to alternatives to Angular. My challenge is, my site has a hierarchical structure.

```
/Home
  /About
    /Blog
      index.html
      post1.html
      post2.html
      ...
    /Products
      index.html
      product1.html
      product2.html
      ...
    index.html
  /Contact
    /Online
      form.html
  index.html
```

Most SPA apps I see are only one level deep. In addition, I can't animate the navigation items associated with each level. In other words, when I click a link at the top level, I would expect the sub-navigation items to animate in. The other problem is dynamically loading content. I don't want to load my app when it initially loads, instead, I want to defer loading of content until its needed.

Can anyone recommend a SPA framework to help me address this challenge? I don't think I can tackle this problem with Angular 1.3. The router in Angular 2.0 look like a potential option. For now though, it does not look viable.

Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views

Comment: You can always do this with history.pushState as shown here: http://html5demos.com/history

Comment: I should be more precise, you can do `pushState` to change the URL (to whatever path you want) and save a JSON object called the state.  When somebody clicks the back button a `popstate` event will be triggered that you can listen for.  The event.state attribute will have your object (which you use to redraw the page accordingly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My challenge is, my site has a hierarchical structure

There is nothing about SPA or AngularJS that makes a hierarchical structure harder than a 1-level flat structure. The built-in angular router can handle this just fine.

> In addition, I can't animate the navigation items associated with each level.

Well, post a detailed question about that, but maybe take a step back and think about "animated navigation". Sounds like low-usability, distracting, unnecessary behavior to me. You look to be building a basic marketing and sales site for some company. Not sure animated navigation should be a major concern.

> I don't want to load my app when it initially loads, instead, I want to defer loading of content until its needed.

This is also almost certainly premature optimization and misuse of engineering cost/effort. Defer loading of content (HTML and text) perhaps but probably not code (javascript). Splitting an app up into deferred-loading modules is for apps with 100 developers and huge codebases with multiple complex areas (think airbnb, facebook). Chances of you realistically needing to do this and having it be a worthwhile effort (cost/benefit) for your stakeholders are extremely slim.

> I don't think I can tackle this problem with Angular 1.3

I'd recommend trying with the built-in angular 1.3 router first and if you end up wanting multiple distinct states at the same URL path, check out the [angular-ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router).